# PyCharm is terribly slow when editing HTML / CSS / JS

Tags: javascript, python, html, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

PyCharm becomes nearly unresponsive in 5 minutes of editing HTML / CSS / JS code – even typing a single character causes a several seconds lag.

However, everything is absolutely fine when I work with Python. I don't close PyCharm for days and it works smooth.

Restarting PyCharm helps only for a few minutes. I'm on PyCharm 5.0.5 Professional & OS X 10.11.

Comment: @RápliAndrás IDE for another language is not a solution at all :) I use PyCharm for python with Flask / Django, not PHP or Node.js.

Comment: Even with PyCharm Pro I prefer to use a more suitable/light IDE for editing HTML/CSS/JS files. In particular I use Visual Studio Code - https://code.visualstudio.com/ which it is an excellent and light IDE. For convenience, I have setup it as an External Tool - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/external-tools.html in PyCharm and I have assigned a shortcut on it to easily open trhough PyCharm any file I want in VS Code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two solutions:

1. You can disable HTML / CSS / JS inspections in `Preferences -> Editor -> Inspections`.
2. If your project has a decent amount of third-party libraries (jquery, bootstrap etc.), this might be the reason. Don't index directories with these libraries: right click on a folder and then choose `Mark Directory As -> Excluded`.

Don't forget to clear the cache: `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`.